# How to safely send message to a running function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to work this code:

```js
var foo=0
window.onmouseup=function(){
    foo=1
}
window.onmousedown=function(){
    while(foo==0);
    console.log("bar")
}
```

the "bar" is not shown and the browser (I use Edge) stuck there(unable to close the page), I had to use Ctrl+T and then Ctrl+W

I guess the problem is `foo==0` is optimized, so it reads from the cache, but I don't know how to avoid it. Or are there other methods?

Comment: as long as javascript is running, it doesn't receive any events. You have to rewrite your while loop into a "breakable" one, e.g. with a setTimeout

Comment: Why not just move the code after the while loop from `mousedown` to `mouseup`?

Comment: so why is my loop "unbreakable"?

Comment: @Rojo it's just an example, i want to do things between

Comment: The loop is currently synchronous, meaning no other javascript will run while that loop is active. That's what @georg was explaining above. Since you have no other logic to close the loop, it will never stop running once it is executed.

Comment: thanks  to daddygames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setInterval()` and put the if statement and the rest of the code in there:

```js
var foo = 0
window.onmouseup = function() {
  foo = 1
}
window.onmousedown = function() {
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (foo !== 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("bar")
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I think the problem is that your while loop will just continue running until it "breaks", or ends the loop. However, `foo` will always be `1` and never `0` after `mouseup`, therefore the program gets stuck in the while loop forever, and no other tasks on the browser including the important ones get run.

TL:DR program stuck on `while`